# Inconsistency with std::cout - failing to print on specific numbers

Tags: c++, cout, factors

I'm running a program to factorise a large number, which outputs each factor it finds as it goes through, smallest to largest. It works fine for numbers below the 1 billion mark, as far as I have tested, but I get a very strange bug when I input 1185914148403 to the program - the factor of 311 will not print.The modulus division returns 0, and it enters the inner while loop, but it won't print 311 unless I explicitly check for that case. For low values, like 622, 311 prints just fine, but here, the smaller factors print, and everything except the printing works fine, and yet nothing is printed. What could possibly be going on?

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>  
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

void nextPrime(std::vector<long long>& primes);

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    int startTime=clock();
    long long  num=std::stol(argv[1]);
    long long  largest=1;
    std::vector<long long>primes;
    primes.push_back(2);
    while(1)                      //iterate through the prime list, divide the num down as far as pos - done when num=1
    {
        long long prime=primes[primes.size()-1]; //the largest prime, the one we care about
        while(!(num%prime)) //while that prime divides, divide down
        {
            num/=prime;
            largest=prime;
            std::cout<<std::endl<<prime;
            if(prime==311)
            {
                //std::cout<<std::endl<<prime;
            }
        }
        if(num==1)      //once we divide down by the largest prime factor, it'll hit 1, and we're done
        {
            break;
        }
        nextPrime(primes);
        long long newPrime=primes[primes.size()-1];
        if(newPrime>num)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    int endTime=clock();
    double timeTaken=(endTime-startTime)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    std::cout<<"\nThat took "<<timeTaken<<" seconds\n";
    std::cout<<"The largest prime factor of "<<std::stol(argv[1])<<" is "<<largest<<"\n";
}

void nextPrime(std::vector<long long>& primes)
{
    long long largest=primes[primes.size()-1];
    long long maybe=largest+1;
    long long pt=0;
    while(1)//check all the primes up to sqrt of the maybe-prime
    {
        long long prime=primes[pt];
        if(prime*prime>maybe)
        {
            primes.push_back(maybe);
            return;
        }
        if(!(maybe%prime))         //if the prime is a factor, it's not prime-try next, and go back to 1st prime
        {
            maybe++;
            pt=0;
            continue;
        }
        else            //if not, check the next prime
        {
            pt++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `long long largest=primes[primes.size()-1];` --  This is better: `long long largest=primes.back();`  Also, you should learn to use the debugger to step through your program.

Comment: Even though you are storing it in a `long long`, the value returned by `std::stol` is just a long, you probably want `std::stoll` instead.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles `std::stol` throws for out-of-range input, so I guess this means OP has 64-bit `long` if execution seems to proceed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, that does look better - not seen that before. And I'm writing in nano  - so I haven't got a debugger. Thought I'd try and take on the IDEless wilderness after a first few months in visual studio

Comment: @M.M surely that wouldn't have any effect further down in the program though?

Comment: You probably have "gdb" available to you as a debugger if you are editing with Nano.

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
std::cout<<std::endl<<prime;
```

Maybe you meant:

```
std::cout << prime << std::endl;
```

This will print the prime and then [flush the output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush).   For the number `1185914148403`, there is an early factor `311` and then no more factors for a while.

Your algorithm is very slow and takes a long time before it finds any other factor.  Since you did not flush the output after outputting the first `311`, then depending on your compiler, you may not have that number appear on screen for a very long time.

---

As noted in comments, `std::stol` returns a `long`, however your program works with `long long`. Since you did not get an out-of-range exception thrown, this indicates that you are on a system where `long` is 64-bit. But it would be good to fix this anyway and use `std::stoll`.

Comment: What do you mean by "flush the output"? I normally use "\n" for linebreaks, I only used std::endl just to see if it bugged out with both methods. I don't think there is much of a difference though.

Comment: @MontyEvans "flush the output" means that any text you have sent to an output stream, should actually appear on the output device instead of sitting in a buffer.  `endl` is equivalent to `\n` followed by `flush`.  It's common for output streams to default to line-buffering, meaning that any text you output without `\n` following it may not appear until there is actually a `\n` sent, or a `flush` command.